# Laravel - How to validate using response and give response

Tags: laravel

I am writing a validation request in Laravel endpoint in the code below

```
public function validationrequest(Request $request)
{

    //log information
     $notification = new NotificationLog();
     $notification->error_message = (string)$request;
     $notification->save();

$password = $request->header('Password');
$username = $request->header('Username');

    $msisdn=$request->msisdn;
    $useresponse=$request->userresponse;
    $useroption=$request->useroption;
    $hash=$request->hash;
    $hash_key="CIA152515276585";

    $data=$msisdn.$useresponse.$useroption.$hash_key;
    $hashed = hash('sha512',$data);
//      return $hashed ;

if($username=="hdf" && $password=="980!-=_hff")
{ 
      if($hashed==$hash)
      {
      //implemetation 
     $ref_id=self::gen_uuid();
     $total_amount=456;
     $statuscode="00";
     $statusMsg = "Successful";
     $message="Welcome To BBNaija 2019";
     $data = $total_amount.$message.$statuscode.$statusMsg.$hash_key;
     $hashed = hash('sha512',$data);
     //adding saving user response
      $user_response=new User_Response;
      $user_response->msisdn=$msisdn;
      $user_response->answer=$useroption;
      $user_response->user_channel="GTB-737";
      $user_response->game_code=$useresponse;
      $user_response->save();
        return response()->json([
         'amount'=>$total_amount,
          'statusCode'=>$statuscode,
           'statusMessage'=>$statusMsg,
            'message'=>$message,
              'hash'=>$hashed
            ]);

}
else
{

    return response(['errorMsg' =>"99", 'description' =>"Invalid haskey"]);
}
}
else
{
    return response(['errorMsg' =>"99", 'description' =>"Invalid username and password"]);
}

    }
```

I want it to be inside after being saved.

> if($username=="gtpay" && $password=="678!-=_bbnaija1234")

```
>If it is successful:

>If $user_response->game_code = 101: JSS 1 succeesfully saved 
>If $user_response->game_code = 102: JSS 2 succeesfully saved
>If $user_response->game_code = 103: JSS 3 succeesfully saved
```

How do I achieve this and give response to the submission. I want the validation to be after save before the else statement

Answer (score 0):

```php
    ...
    if($username=="hdf" && $password=="980!-=_hff")
    {
        ...
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ];

        $request->validate($rules);
        ...
```

Does the standard validation implementation not work well enough?

You can read more about rules etc. in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation).

Having said that, it's better practice to create request validation classes and validate all data before persisting it in the database.